# InputStreamReader(InputStreamReader(System.in,"ISO-8859-15")) reads "ő" as "õ"

Tags: java, console, diacritics, inputstreamreader

First, I read from file. Reading is fine `ő`.

Then, I enter `ő` in console and if I compare them I got false. I want `ő` with console reading as well.

Edit: I use `InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(file)` for reading file.

Comment: are you using bufferedreader in both the cases?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, it looks like you are attempting to compare 2 different objects with each other,  try the `.equals(object)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `windows-1250` encoding. (Java doesn't support `ISO-8859-16`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `InputStreamReader(System.in, "ISO-8859-16")` instead.

[ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) does not contain the character `ő`  but [ISO-8859-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16) does. Furthermore `ő` is code point `0151` in ISO-8859-16 which is the same code point as `ö` in ISO-8859-15 which explains your current result.

Comment: I've tried before, but something weird happened. My code printed "ISO-8859-16" and I couldn't entry any data.

Comment: @junpet, show more of your code (how exactly are you reading data from the file and from the console, and how exactly are you comparing the results), otherwise it's difficult to help you.